# Github action Post Run fails workflow

Tags: git, github, github-actions, workflow, golangci-lint

Someone know what is it and how to fix such behavior?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDMFV.png)

I tried to rerun workflow and it hepls

But I want to prevent this in the future it happens quite often

Let me know any solytion that can help to solve this problem